# About maximum and minimum

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Let $0 \le \sin^2(\alpha) +2\cos(\alpha)\le \frac{1}{2} $ now :

> find $max \sin(\alpha)  $ and  ,$min \sin(\alpha) $

We have $\sin^2(\alpha)= 1- \cos^2(\alpha) $ now let $\cos(\alpha)= x $ then we have $0 \le 1- x^2 +2x\le \frac{1}{2} $ now we must find $max (x)$ and $min (x)$ and note that $-1 \le x \le 1$ is this true ?

Comment: I agree with your analysis, and with your approach of maximizing $\sin(x)$ by minimizing $\cos(x)$ and vice-versa.  Note, that it may not be that simple, if (for example) $\sin(x) < 0$ or $\cos(x) < 0$ is possible.  But the approach that you have taken is what my 1st step would be.  If $f(x) = 1 - x^2 + 2x,$ then what is $f'(x)$ and what is $f''(x)$?

Comment: So, $f'(x) = 0 \implies x = 1 \implies f(x) = 2$, which is out of bounds.  Further, $x < 1 \implies f'(x) > 0$.  Therefore, for all viable values of $x$, you have that $f(x)$ is a strictly increasing function.

Answer (score 1):

we have $0 \le2- ( 1-\cos(\alpha) )^2\le \frac{1}{2} $ so we must have $   -1 \le \cos(\alpha) <0$  then the answers of equations $2- ( 1-\cos(\alpha) )^2=0 $
and         $2- ( 1-\cos(\alpha) )^2 =\frac{1}{2} $ is maximum and minimum.